# How to integrate FxCop and VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, integration, fxcop

If this is duplicated question, please point me to the proper link and I'll delete this question.

I know that in VS Team System I can use Code Analysis but I'm using VS Professional.

Can you tell me how I can integrate FxCop and Visual Studio?  I don't want to add FxCopCmd.exe to my Post-build events to run FxCop with every compilation.
I want to be able to run FxCop when I choose by right clicking on the project in Solution Explorer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It took awhile by I finally figure it out.  It's not ideal but it works.

**Update:**
I create a post with [step by step instructions](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/integrate-fxcop-1-36-vs-2008/):

Thanks to [aamit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83479/aamit), who provided the link that put me on the right track even that solution in MSDN article doesn't work.  Give him +1; he deserves it.

1.) In FxCop GUI save your project.

**IMPORTANT**:

- a. Save project in the same directory
  where your solution is.
- b. Give the FxCop project name the
  same as your solution name and
  include the .sln extension.

For example:  If your solution name is `MySolution.sln`, the FxCop project name is going to be `MySolution.sln.FxCop`.

2.) In Visual Studio select Tools -> External Toos

3.) Enter following information in External Tools dialog box:

- Title: **FxCop**
- Command: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft
  FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe**
- Arguments: **/c
  /p:"$(SolutionDir)\$(SolutionFileName).fxcop"
  /cXsl:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft
  FxCop 1.36\Xml\VSConsoleOutput.xsl"**
- Initial directory: **C:\Program
  Files\Microsoft FxCop 1.36**

Make sure that **"Use Output window"** checkbox is checked.

That's it.  It works for me I hope it's going to work for you.

Comment: Does SuppressMessage attribute works if I call to fxcopcmd.exe using command line?

Answer (score 16):

How about setting up FxCop as an external tool in Visual Studio? Here's the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429389(VS.80).aspx

Comment: +1 for giving the link.  The information in the link doesn't work but it gave me an idea how to solve this problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I run a command very similar Vadim's as a Post-Build event for the project. That way, I get the FxCop errors as soon as I recompile. But our commands are pretty much the same; nice to know at least two people in the world reached the same conclusion!

The errors do show up in Visual Studo's Error List pane.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft FxCop 1.36\FxCopCmd.exe"
/file:"$(TargetPath)" 
/console
/dictionary:"$(SolutionDir)Res\FxCop\CustomDictionary.xml"
/searchgac 
/ignoregeneratedcode
```

(You can omit the /dictionary argument; it just points to one of my custom dictionary files since FxCop flags a few variable names as Hungarian notation when they aren't. I also line-wrapped the command for readability.)

It does make the build a little longer, but it's nice to see the errors right away and to tailor the command settings per project. Good luck!