# Doing .NET 4.0 static code analysis (FxCop) with VS 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop

I have VS 2010 **Professional** (which, unlike *Premium*, does *not* include access to Code Analysis configuration within the IDE), and a C# 4 solution containing many-dozen projects. I want to do static code analysis as part of solution compilation.

The possible ways I have identified with the help of SO and Google are:

- Edit every `.csproj` in the solution to include an invocation of the stand-alone FxCop 10 as a Post-build event. Pros: happens on every compile for every project that is rebuilt. Cons: Have to take additional measures to ensure new projects have this specified
- Create a new project, or identify an existing project, that is always built last, on account of its project dependencies. Give (just) that project a Post-build event that runs FxCop on all the assemblies in the (common) output folder. Pros: only one file to update, and less possibility of future projects going unanalysed. Cons: The vagaries of build dependencies might mean this doesn't actually work
- Update all developers' VS instances with an add-in or macro that runs FxCop after any build. Don't really like this idea at all.

Are there any other options, that are clearly better than any of the above? Are there any caveats or observations I need to be aware of to make one of the above work?

I also want FxCop to be run as part of a `MSBuild 4.0`-powered build on a build server. Which of the options will allow me to reuse code analysis rulesets between desktop compilation and bulid server compilation?

---

*I have already read related but non-identical already-existing questions including:*

- [FxCop for .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740738/fxcop-for-net-4-0) which asks 'is the stand-alone FxCop available yet?'
- [FxCop on build (Visual Studio 2008 Professional)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527948/fxcop-on-build-visual-studio-2008-professional) which is about a single project
- [How to integrate FxCop and VS 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841704/how-to-integrate-fxcop-and-vs-2008) which is about making FxCop-invocation available ad hoc, on a context menu click

Comment: Yuck.  Upgrade your license, this stuff only makes sense if your time is worthless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To integrate FxCop as part of the build scipt (MSBuild) I use the FxCop task from [MSBuild.Community.Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).  Using FxCop I create an FxCop project (FxCopProject.FxCop) that defines the rules to use and the assemblies to examine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\vendor\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.v1.3.0.504</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  <FxCopDir>vendor\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0</FxCopDir>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

 <Target Name='FxCopReport'>
  <FxCop
   ToolPath='$(FxCopDir)'
   ProjectFile='FxCopProject.FxCop'
   AnalysisReportFileName='FxCopReport.xml'
  />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Hudson](http://www.hudson-ci.org) as a build server that would perform code analysis after building .NET applications. In order to use it for this purpose, you will need to install two plugins:

- [MSBuild](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/MSBuild+Plugin) plugin to build .NET applications.
- [Violations](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Violations) plugin that reports code analysis results and supports FxCop and StyleCop.

Hudson would need to be configured to execute FxCop and StyleCop, but this isn't very difficult to do using batch files. The benefit is that none of your project files would need to be configured, as the code analysis would be performed externally; that is, not through Visual Studio.

You can configure Hudson to perform the code analysis as a daily task or even on every change to your applications. Then everyone on your development team could view the code analysis results through Hudson to determine whether they've made any violations.

Answer (score 2):

I've not used FxCop for a while, but if you have lots of projects, I suspect running it once for each project, rather than just once at the end, is going to be painful. You could try (or at least start from) something like [this](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/build-automation-for-your-application-using-msbuild/). In a nutshell, you have an uber-project, with targets that depend on building your entire solution, followed by running FxCop (or unit tests, etc.) You invoke the uber-project using a batch file from the Solution Explorer.

It's similar to your second suggestion, but won't have any dependence on the build order, and doesn't require fiddling with new projects. Unfortunately its current incarnation breaks the normal shortcuts for building from within VS, and it'll probably be easy to bypass accidentally, but it might be possible to refine it.

It might also be cleaner and better integrated with VS to use an MSBuild target for running FxCop, rather than a post-build step.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to FxCop would be to use the tool NDepend that lets write [Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries (namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own code rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

Rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom build activity (which runs based on a property we set via the build definition):

1. My custom activity searches for all *.csproj files under the root folder.
2. Updates all the csproj files to add the property "

   true
3. Save the csproj file.
4. Now this will cause the code analysis to run when you compile it.

This means that we have control over when the code analysis need to be run or not. We dont have to run it everytime we build the code.

Just read that you dont have the premium VS, but you can follow the same process to update the csproj file post build event during build time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the best option IMO is to use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarsource.com/) with the C# plugin to do your analysis. This handles FxCop as one of the analysis options as well as being able to do StyleCop and ReSharper analysis (using the free command-line runner) and compiles into one web interface.

It does take a little while to setup the first project but setting up subsequent projects is very similar and can be triggered by your CI server.